# Error when creating jarvis ai, object is not callable, etc

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqzR4.jpg) This is the picture     This is the code for my ai

```
            import datetime
            import webbrowser
            import pyttsx3
            import pywhatkit
            import speech_recognition
            import wikipedia

            engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
            voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
            engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
            engine.setProperty("rate", 150)


            def speak(audio):
                engine.say(audio)
                engine.runAndWait()


            def takeCommand():
                r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
                with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
                    print("Listening...")
                    r.pause_threshold = 4
                    r.energy_threshold = 300
                    audio = r.listen(source, 0, 4)

                try:
                    print("Understanding...")
                    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
                    print(f"You said: {query}\n")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Say that again")
                    return "None"
                return query


            # Starting...............................................................................................................
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                while True:
                    query = takeCommand().lower()
                    if "wake up David" in query:
                        hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
                        if 0 <= hour <= 12:
                            speak("Good Morning sir, how are you?")
                        elif 12 < hour <= 18:
                            speak("Good Afternoon sir, how are you?")

                        else:
                            speak("Good Evening sir, how are you?")

                    while True:
                        query = takeCommand().lower()
                        if "go to sleep david" in query:
                            speak("Ok, See you, Remember if you need anything just say, wake up david")
                            break

                        elif "I'm good how are you" in query:
                            speak("I am also good, how may I help you today?")
                        elif "thank you" in query:
                            speak("You are welcome sir")


            # Web browser searching..................................................................................................

                        def searchGoogle(query):
                            if "google" in query:
                                import wikipedia as googleScrap
                                query = query.replace("david", "")
                                query = query.replace("google search", "")
                                query = query.replace("google", "")
                                speak("This is what I found")
                                try:
                                    pywhatkit.search(query)
                                    result = googleScrap.summary(query, 1)
                                    speak(result)

                                except:
                                    speak("Did not find anything about that, sorry")

                query = query.replace("jarvis", "")
                query = query.replace("google search", "")
                query = query.replace("google", "")
                speak("This is what I found on google")

                try:
                    pywhatkit.search(query)
                    result = googleScrap.summary(query, 1)
                    speak(result)

                finally:
                    speak("No speakable output available")


            def searchYoutube(query):
                if "youtube" in query:
                    speak("This is what I found for your search!")
                    query = query.replace("youtube search", "")
                    query = query.replace("youtube", "")
                    query = query.replace("jarvis", "")
                    web = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
                    webbrowser.open(web)
                    pywhatkit.playonyt(query)
                    speak("Done, Sir")


            def searchWikipedia(query):
                if "wikipedia" in query:
                    speak("Searching from wikipedia....")
                    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                    query = query.replace("search wikipedia", "")
                    query = query.replace("jarvis", "")
                    results = wikipedia.summary(query,sentences=2)
                    speak("According to wikipedia..")
                    print(results)
                    speak(results)
```

These are the error codes I get

line 51, in 
query = takeCommand().lower()

line 25, in takeCommand
audio = r.listen(source, 0, 4)

line 652, in listen
buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)

line 161, in read
return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)

line 608, in read
return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)

KeyboardInterrupt

Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function catch_errors..call_with_this at 0x000001E3FA726560>
Traceback (most recent call last):

line 97, in call_with_this

line 1734, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

These are the modules I have installed:

import datetime
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import speech_recognition
import wikipedia

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242745/discussion-on-question-by-adithya-srivathsa-error-when-creating-jarvis-ai-objec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your `takeCommand()` function with this:

```
def takeCommand():
r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
    speech_recognition.Recognizer().adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2)
    print("Listening...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said:{query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        return "None"
    return query
```

Other than this there are no other errors in your code and for the web scraping functions. You are not actually calling them

**Update**

```
engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty("rate", 150)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 4
        r.energy_threshold = 300
        audio = r.listen(source, 0, 4)

    try:
        print("Understanding...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print(f"You said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again")
        return "None"
    return query

def searchGoogle(query):
    import wikipedia as googleScrap
    speak("This is what I found")
    try:
        pywhatkit.search(query)
        result = googleScrap.summary(query, 1)
        speak(result)

    except:
        speak("Did not find anything about that, sorry")


def searchYoutube(query):
    web = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
    webbrowser.open(web)
    pywhatkit.playonyt(query)
    speak("Done, Sir")


def searchWikipedia(query):
    results = wikipedia.summary(query,sentences=2)
    speak("According to wikipedia..")
    print(results)
    speak(results)


# Starting...............................................................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if "wake up David" in query:
            hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
            if 0 <= hour <= 12:
                speak("Good Morning sir, how are you?")
            elif 12 < hour <= 18:
                speak("Good Afternoon sir, how are you?")

            else:
                speak("Good Evening sir, how are you?")

        while True:
            query = takeCommand().lower()
            if "go to sleep david" in query:
                speak("Ok, See you, Remember if you need anything just say, wake up david")
                break

            elif "I'm good how are you" in query:
                speak("I am also good, how may I help you today?")

            elif "thank you" in query:
                speak("You are welcome sir")

            elif "wikipedia" in query:
                speak("Searching from wikipedia....")
                query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                query = query.replace("search wikipedia", "")
                query = query.replace("jarvis", "")
                searchWikipedia(query)

            elif "youtube" in query:
                speak("This is what I found for your search!")
                query = query.replace("youtube search", "")
                query = query.replace("youtube", "")
                query = query.replace("jarvis", "")
                searchYoutube(query)
            
            elif "google" in query:
                query = query.replace("david", "")
                query = query.replace("google search", "")
                query = query.replace("google", "")
                searchGoogle(query)
```

Comment: I get the same error codes, even after I replaced my takeCommand function

Comment: @RohitNambiar everything else works except my web functions, I do not know how to call them while they are in the loop. If you know please let me know. Thanks

Comment: For some reason, the google command works but the wiki and youtube commands don't work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I do not get any error, it just does not respond.

Comment: So basically you tell it to "search wikipedia" and it does not do anything and it continues listening?

Comment: Yes,that is what it does.

Comment: What did you specifically ask it to do? for example "Search wikipedia"

Comment: Ok, so now the youtube command is working properly, I don't know what happened that made it work. But the wiki is still not working. If I say "Wikipedia India" It does not respond, I tried doing other commands like "Search Wikipedia India" Wikipedia Search India". None of them work.

Comment: Yes, that's because it will only respond when you say for example `wikipedia India` or `search wikipedia India` etc. It is not an intelligent bot because it will only respond when what you say completely matches what it expects. for example the bot expects `wikipedia India` if you say `Wikipedia India` it won't respond, Even a single capital letter will not allow your bot to respond. So you have to customize the bot to either find string similarity or add more query options

Comment: Check out my assistant https://github.com/Rohith-JN/Personal-assistant